# How do I run unittest on a Tkinter app?

Tags: python, unit-testing, tdd, tkinter

I've just begun learning about [TDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development), and I'm developing a program using a Tkinter GUI. The only problem is that once the `.mainloop()` method is called, the test suite hangs until the window is closed.

Here is an example of my code:

```
# server.py
import Tkinter as tk

class Server(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.mainloop()
```

```
# test.py
import unittest
import server

class ServerTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def testClassSetup(self):
       server.Server()
       # and of course I can't call any server.whatever functions here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

What is the appropriate way of testing Tkinter apps? Or is it just 'dont'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can do is spawn the mainloop in a separate thread and use your main thread to run the actual tests; watch the mainloop thread as it were.  Make sure you check the state of the Tk window before doing your asserts.

Multithreading any code is hard.  You may want to break your Tk program down into testable pieces instead of unit testing the entire thing at once (which really isn't unit testing).

I would finally suggest testing at least at the control level if not lower for your program, it will help you tremendously.

Comment: After thinking about it for a few days (and working on other projects) this makes a lot more sense - having a processing class that the GUI interfaces with should make it easier to test, and maybe easier to write, too.

Comment: The Tk event-loop needs to run in the main-thread.  So use the spawned thread for the tests.

Comment: Doesn't work. Any `self.tk.call()` for a widget freezes if `mainloop()` is running in another thread.

Comment: @ankostis All tkinter calls including event loops should run in the same thread that you created your `Tk()` window.

Answer (score 14):

**Bottom line: pump the events with the below code after an action that causes a UI event, before a later action that needs the effect of that event.**

---

IPython provides an elegant solution without threads it its `gui tk` magic command implementation that's located in [`terminal/pt_inputhooks/tk.py`](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/terminal/pt_inputhooks/tk.py).

Instead of `root.mainloop()`, it runs `root.dooneevent()` in a loop, checking for exit condition (an interactive input arriving) each iteration. This way, the even loop doesn't run when IPython is busy processing a command.

With tests, there's no external event to wait for, and the test is always "busy", so one has to manually (or semi-automatically) run the loop at "appropriate moments". What are they?

Testing shows that without an event loop, one can change the widgets directly (with `<widget>.tk.call()` and anything that wraps it), but event handlers never fire. So, the loop needs to be run whenever an event happens and we need its effect -- i.e. after any operation that changes something, before an operation that needs the result of the change.

The code, derived from the aforementioned IPython procedure, would be:

```
def pump_events(root):
    while root.dooneevent(_tkinter.ALL_EVENTS|_tkinter.DONT_WAIT):
        pass
```

That would process (execute handlers for) all pending events, and all events that would directly result from those.

<sup>([`tkinter.Tk.dooneevent()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_tkinter.c#L2887) delegates to [`Tcl_DoOneEvent()`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclLib/DoOneEvent.htm).)</sup>

---

As a side note, using this instead:

```
root.update()
root.update_idletasks()
```

would not necessarily do the same because neither function processes *all* kinds of events. Since every handler may generate other arbitrary events, this way, I can't be sure that I've processed everything.

---

Here's an example that tests a simple popup dialog for editing a string value:

```
class TKinterTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    """These methods are going to be the same for every GUI test,
    so refactored them into a separate class
    """
    def setUp(self):
        self.root=tkinter.Tk()
        self.pump_events()

    def tearDown(self):
        if self.root:
            self.root.destroy()
            self.pump_events()

    def pump_events(self):
        while self.root.dooneevent(_tkinter.ALL_EVENTS | _tkinter.DONT_WAIT):
            pass

class TestViewAskText(TKinterTestCase):
    def test_enter(self):
        v = View_AskText(self.root,value=u"йцу")
        self.pump_events()
        v.e.focus_set()
        v.e.insert(tkinter.END,u'кен')
        v.e.event_generate('<Return>')
        self.pump_events()

        self.assertRaises(tkinter.TclError, lambda: v.top.winfo_viewable())
        self.assertEqual(v.value,u'йцукен')


# ###########################################################
# The class being tested (normally, it's in a separate module
# and imported at the start of the test's file)
# ###########################################################

class View_AskText(object):
    def __init__(self, master, value=u""):
        self.value=None

        top = self.top = tkinter.Toplevel(master)
        top.grab_set()
        self.l = ttk.Label(top, text=u"Value:")
        self.l.pack()
        self.e = ttk.Entry(top)
        self.e.pack()
        self.b = ttk.Button(top, text='Ok', command=self.save)
        self.b.pack()

        if value: self.e.insert(0,value)
        self.e.focus_set()
        top.bind('<Return>', self.save)

    def save(self, *_):
        self.value = self.e.get()
        self.top.destroy()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import unittest
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 4):

**This answer is for Python 3.7 and up (whatever versions have async methods)**

In your `main.py` or wherever you start your main UI:

```py
def start_application() -> Application:
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Application(master=root)
    app.load_settings()
    return app # will return the application without starting the main loop.

if __name__=='__main__':
    start_application().mainloop()
```

And in your `tests.py`:

```py
from myapp.main import start_application

class TestGui(unittest.TestCase):
    
    # this will run on a separate thread.
    async def _start_app(self):
        self.app.mainloop()
    
    def setUp(self):
        self.app = start_application()
        self._start_app()
    
    def tearDown(self):
        self.app.destroy()
    
    def test_startup(self):
        title = self.app.winfo_toplevel().title()
        expected = 'The Application My Boss Wants Me To Make'
        self.assertEqual(title, expected)
```

This won't show anything but it will pass. In addition, expect a warning to be
shown saying we didn't await `_start_application`. This can be ignored in this context. (If you wanted to be a stickler for multi-threading then you'll have to do your own thread management...imho it's too much work for unit testing).

Comment: The `app` in the `start_application` is not a Tkinter object, so the Application has no attribute `mainloop`.

Comment: in the `start_application`, should return root. And everything would work as expected in the unittest.

Comment: Thank you for your anser. How did you figure out this solution?

Comment: Is it possible to move the code inside `setup()` to `setUpClass()`? Because my tkinter application takes a few seconds to initialize. I want it to be setup for only 1 time.

Comment: Why not await `start_application` in `tearDown`?

Comment: _"This won't show anything"_ -- then it doesn't test properly. When do you run asyncore's main loop? Looks like never. It only happens to work for this particular test because here, event handlers are not needed to have run -- but for other cases, they may be.

Answer (score 2):

There is a technique called monkey-patching, whereby you change code at runtime.

You could monkey-patch the TK class, so that mainloop doesn't actually start the program.

Something like this in your test.py (untested!):

```
import tk
class FakeTk(object):
    def mainloop(self):
        pass

tk.__dict__['Tk'] = FakeTk
import server

def test_server():
    s = server.Server()
    server.mainloop() # shouldn't endless loop on you now...
```

A mocking framework like [mock](http://python-mock.sourceforge.net/) makes this a lot less painful.

Comment: This is the best route. I eventually came to suspect that Tk does not shut down cleanly between unittests. (I use the unittest module from the standard library.) It does get a little more complicated if the class is a complex of tkinter widgets. In TDD you have to instantiate the object for testing while monkey patching any attempt to start Tk. This even affects the implementation of `__str__` and `__repr__`.

Comment: Without Tk logic involved, you can't be sure that your actions have the desired affect on the UI.

Comment: Agree, but that's not a unit test. I'd test that in another way, perhaps with a script that automates the UI.

Comment: Testing shows that without a `mainloop()` running, I can change widgets directly (with `tk.call`s and anything that wraps them), but event handlers never fire. So, the UI is broken this way and it's thus meaningless to test it.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how this would work with `mock`?