# Is there a good example of functional testing a Tkinter application?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, functional-testing

I found a great website that discusses functional testing of a Python GUI application using [`IronPython`](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/testing), but I want to use Tkinter and am having a hard time making the transition between the libraries.

Michael shows this example for IronPython:

```py
class FunctionalTest(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.mainForm = None
        self._thread = Thread(ThreadStart(self.startMultiDoc))
        self._thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
        self._thread.Start()
        while self.mainForm is None:
            Thread.CurrentThread.Join(100)

        def invokeOnGUIThread(self, function):
            return self.mainForm.Invoke(CallTarget0(function))
```

I'm having a hard time translating that into how I would hook into a Tkinter based application that would have the base setup:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
ttk.Button(root, text="Hello World").grid()
root.mainloop()
```

I'm thinking you would want to run a method on the main root object in the second thread as well but I'm not seeing an equivalent method to the `mainForm.Invoke()`.  Maybe I'm thinking about it wrong.  Maybe functional testing GUI applications in this manner is not so common?

Comment: Related: [How do I run unittest on a Tkinter app?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4083796/3357935)

Answer (score 1):

To a Tkinter-based application, the approach would be different.
In a Tkinter-based application you can to use the trace method of a StringVar or IntVar. Like this:

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

```
def on_value_change(*args):
    print("Value changed to:", var.get())

root = Tk()
var = StringVar()
var.trace("w", on_value_change) # detect changes in the variable
ttk.Entry(root, textvariable=var).grid()
root.mainloop()
```